# Change address tool in google webmaster after implemented 301

Tags: google-search-console

I've moved my website, but I've already added htaccess with 301 redirect. Now if I go to webmaster tools it says that site is not verified. How can I "tell" google that we've changed domain name?

Comment: new domain new verification required.

Answer (score 2):

Re upload the new html file which Google webmasters will give you to your server and that should solve your problem. I would also recommend setting a preferred domain in the webmasters e.g www.mysite.com or mysite.com it tells them the preferred url you would like to rank in the Google index.

Answer (score 1):

You can Verify you site my adding a TXT Record and a CNAME record through your domain provider. Google will provide you with all the directions you will need. In GWT just click Verify Site - > Select your domain provider and follow the instructions that will look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to verify a site is to follow google's recommended way of downloading a super small HTML file thats named something that's hard for a layman to understand. Then place that file inside the document root of the website to verify. This is the same folder where your index.html file is located (or whatever index file you use as your homepage).
Once you copied the file, go back to webmaster tools and click the verify button and you should immediately see a check mark indicating the site is verified. Just make sure the file stays in place and that it is accessible to the world. Google should be the only one that will be accessing it at random times to prove you own the site.